# How can a Google Cloud Logging user be limited to view logs from a specific deployment?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-iam, google-cloud-logging

My company currently have a legacy GCP project that has multiple deployments running in the same kubernetes namespace. Before time can be found to separate the the deployments to their projects, I would like to give certain users access to the (Cloud Logging) logs of specific deployments e.g team_A should only be able to see the logs of deployment_A in the default namespace.

Google has [IAM conditions](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/conditions-overview), however I cannot find the right name nor type to use. There's a [big list](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/conditions-resource-attributes), but am I missing something? Is this not possible?

[image: Conditions dialog]

Answer (score 2):

You can use RBAC Authorization for this kind of fine tuned access control:

- https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/
- https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/role-based-access-control

For example, you can create a custom ClusterRole with only `pods/log` as resource, core as apiGroups and get as verb. And then you create a RoleBinding for at the default namespace which is binding the custom ClusterRole to your users / group.

If you are using Google groups, maybe you need to check also this documentation: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/google-groups-rbac

Comment: I'm checking if this is the only way to do it. Support staff will require access too and they don't have a command line - in fact they are GUI users. I was hoping to only use Cloud Logging, but that allows them to see logs for everything in the project. I should probably edit the question to mention that this is about Cloud Logging.

Thank you though